# Visual Studio can't find Add-in Manager

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, monodevelop, monogame

I am following an online tutorial on the [Xamarin Docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/game_development/monogame/introduction/part1/) the problem is it says

> On Windows, select* Tools > *Add-in Manager... . Select the Gallery tab, expand the Game Development category and select MonoGame Addin, then click Install:

But I cant find "Add-in Manager" in the Tools drop-down menu, the tutorial says to create a *Universal MonoGame Mobile application* project but I have Monogame installed but don't see that option so I guess that I need to do the thing with the add-in manager first

other:
I am using Visual Studio 2017

Main Problem:
Can't find a *Universal MonoGame Mobile application* option when creating a new project, but I see other monogame options such as Android and IOS.

Comment: Those docs are out-of-date for Windows (that quoted line is from the deprecated Xamarin Studio). Install MonoGame for Visual Studio by downloading the installer: http://www.monogame.net/2017/03/01/monogame-3-6/

Comment: @SushiHangover I installed it but I cant find the Universal MonoGame Mobile application option

Comment: The "Universal MonoGame Mobile application" is just a shared project. You can create an Xamarin.Android MG application project, an Xamarin.iOS application MG project and then add a `Shared Project` to the solution and reference it by both the Xamarin application projects.

Comment: @SushiHangover I'm sorta new to this, is this correct? https://imgur.com/a/Wzc8N

Comment: @SushiHangover When trying to run it, i got "The type or namespace name 'Content' does not exist in the namespace 'Xarmarin.Android' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Comment: If you look in the `IDE/MonoDevelop` source directory you can find how the  templates are structured: https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/tree/develop/IDE/MonoDevelop